# PayPal BillSafe Integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway

In a project I need to integrate PayPal BillSafe as payment gateway.

I visited the official website for it https://www.billsafe.de/

The problem is that the site is in German, even documentation is also in german.

I don't need anyone to translate but after reading comments in SDK, I just needed to know about following methods of billsafe what they are for and what they will do.

List is as follows:

```
prepareOrder
getTransactionResult
getPaymentInstruction
reportShipment
updateArticleList
getTransactionId
getPayoutStatus
getAgreedHandlingCharges
reportDirectPayment,
setOrderNumber
setInvoiceNumber
getArticleList
pauseTransaction
prevalidateOrder
getSettlement
revertReportShipment
processOrde
```

These methods/options are provided to do payment but what it exactly does is not clear to me! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the message on the front page about billsafe being discontinued? They suggest you use Paypal Plus instead which luckily for you seems to have a English documentation :)

Comment: Thanks @B8vrede but I was told to integrate billsafe! But now I got the reason to slip away! ;) justKidding! Thank you bdw